# write a SP or function that takes the parameter (Day,frequency, and date) and calculates the nexttransaction Date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have been struggling to write a SP or function. The requirement is to compute the NextTransactionDate based on the input parameters passed - Day (Monday, Tuesday, etc), Frequency (Monthly, Bi-Weekly, Semi-Monthly,Weekly), and  Date( Date where you would apply the logic).

Example, Let's say, you pass Day = Friday, Frequency as Bi-Weekly and Date=05/05/2011. The output should be the friday (day) 2 weeks (Bi-Weekly) from the Date (state) so In this example, May 20, 2011.
For Monthly, it should be end of the month(business day). Appreciate your help if you already have such a SP.

Comment: Thats a pretty broad request. I think this would be best served as a user defined function (UDF). I would suggest showing some effort by posting a CREATE FUNCTION stub that at least has the proper signature (parameters and return type).

Answer (score 0):

I think you've gotten your answer already :) [How to get NextDayofWeek if you pass the date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077352/how-to-get-nextdayofweek-if-you-pass-the-date)